# Finding complicated unique elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two following arrays:

```
a = [[1,'string',2,3],[2,'otherstring', 6,1],[1, 'otherstring',2,3]]
b = [[7,'anotherstring',4,3],[1,'string',2,3]]
```

which in real of course are a lot bigger.
I need to find unique elements:

```
>>> unique(a,b)
[[1,"string",2,3],[2,'otherstring', 6,1],
    [1, 'otherstring',2,3],[7,'anotherstring',4,3]]
```

I thought about [numpy.unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) yet it seems to serve a bit another function, since:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 3]])
>>> np.unique(a)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

NOTE: **list(set(a+b))** doesn't work since list is not hashable.

Comment: Is there a problem with turning your sub-lists into sets/frozensets?

Comment: @WayneWerner I think this would work only if turn them into tuples which seems to be a super complicated way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set(tuple(item) for item in a+b)
```

output:

```
set([(2, 'otherstring', 6, 1), (1, 'string', 2, 3), (7, 'anotherstring', 4, 3), (1, 'otherstring', 2, 3)])
```

Comment: This is one way to do it. Yet i'd use map:  **set(map(tuple, a+b))**

Comment: @galaxyan you actually can turn generator to set so you do no need [] in your first line.

Comment: @UpmostScarab yes. sorry for it. bad hobby

Comment: The brackets in the output are important; it's the brackets in the input that weren't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package can solve such problems in a vectorized manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.unique(tuple(zip(a+b)))
```